# How to add series label to the line graph in java?

Tags: java, graph, frame, jfreechart, linegraph

I wants to add label to the graph like
 [image] 
 what i am getting  is 
[image] 
 I am not able add these series names to the graphs like in above one(drawn using excel).
 codes are here

```
        // Population in 2005

        Random rand = new Random();

        // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999
        //int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000);
        /*for(int i=0;i<12;++i){
            dataset.addValue(status(code.getText(),dater(i)), "Status", monthname(i));
            }*/
        for(int i=0;i<12;++i){
        dataset.addValue(2500+rand.nextInt(1000), "USA", String.valueOf(2000+i));
        dataset.addValue(2000+rand.nextInt(1000), "India", String.valueOf(2000+i));
        dataset.addValue(1500+rand.nextInt(1000), "China", String.valueOf(2000+i));
        }

        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(analysisof(code.getText()), "Year", "Amount", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot barchrt = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
        barchrt.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.orange);
        ChartPanel barpanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
        panelchart.removeAll();
        panelchart.add(barpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelchart.validate();
        this.repaint();
```

Comment: These two graphs are of different data but the label like first graph i.e. series1,series2,series3. It want this series label in the second graph using java.

Comment: What happens when you set the _legend_ parameter to `true` in your `ChartFactory`?

Comment: It's working. Thanks @trashgod

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20legend%20parameter), the *legend* parameter specified in your chosen [`ChartFactory`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) is passed unchanged to the [factory's](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/e746961d1f5735226d786268eae0eef0213cf0c4/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L978) [`JFreeChart`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) constructor as "a flag specifying whether or not a legend is required." Setting the value to `true` adds a `LegendTitle` to the chart.

```
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
    …
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
    true, // legend
    true, // tooltips
    false // urls
);
```